# $\{\hat f,\hat h\}=0$ and $\{\hat g,\hat h\}=0$ doesn't imply $\{\hat f,\hat g\}=0$?

Tags: operator-theory

I'm reading (Russian edition of) [Landau & Lifshitz "Quantum Mechanics"](http://books.google.ru/books?id=SvdoN3k8EysC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), and there is a statement like this (page 15 in link):

> We note that, if $\{\hat f,\hat h\}=0$ and $\{\hat g,\hat h\}=0$ , it doesn't generally follow that $\hat f$ and $\hat g$ commute.

But if $\hat f$ shares eigenvectors with $\hat h$, and $\hat g$ also shares eigenvectors with $\hat h$, shouldn't they share eigenvectors of each other and thus commute?

Comment: Nope. Just take $\hat{h} = 1$ (the identity operator). Indeed, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ will both commute with $1$, and yet $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ don't commute, do they?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić BTW, is it in this case because of degenerate spectrum of unity operator, which allows to use any vector as eigenvector?

Comment: That's a good way to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Just take $\hat{h}=1$ (the identity operator), which automatically commutes with every operator. Indeed, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ will both commute with $1$, even though $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ famously don't commute.